# I want to recommend a book, or review it... How can I ask that in the form of a question?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just got [Anatoly Zak's](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/zak.html) book on the Russian space program, and it is AWESOME!

I would love to be able to recommend or review it. But I am at a loss of how to do so, in the format appropriate for the site?

Can I ask it in the form of a question somehow? Maybe answer myself?

What would be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 5):

The appropriate format is the site blog. Of course, we don't have a blog, so that's a bit problematic... Short of that, brag about it in chat?

Answer (score 4):

To add to what PearsonArtPhoto said ...

Well, in a way, you just did. At least you've exposing the author somewhat, which I see nothing wrong with. If you deem the book a proper gem like you seem to, then it wouldn't go amiss adding it to the [list of literary canons on the topic of interplanetary space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/49), if it belongs there, which should lend it a bit more exposure for being properly endorsed by our meta content editors.

On the main Q&A site however, explicit product endorsements are strictly off-topic, and since this is a book that sells, it is a product. There are however ways to increase user awareness of it through indirect questions, such as the ones you'd get by reading the book, and then mentioning where you got the idea from, quoting a most relevant paragraph, and so on, as long as endorsing the book isn't the main point you're trying to make. Possibilities are really endless to subtly mention it with your contribution still remaining acceptable, but please don't use referral links to the product, or anything like that.

By the way, Anatoly Zak's Twitter account is [@RussianSpaceWeb](https://twitter.com/RussianSpaceWeb)