# What are the best books to learn about space exploration?

Tags: discussion

I would like to learn more about space exploration; what technology we have, how specific satellite technologies work, rocket design etc.

What books would you advise to read?

Where would you advise to start?

Comment: Thank you @uhoh this is precisely what I was searching for.

Comment: "Ignition!: An Informal History of Liquid Rocket Propellants" is a well-loved classic if you are into stuff that goes boom.

Comment: @Jokz now that we are here in meta, do you think that your question is answered by answers to [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249)? If so, we can vote to close this as duplicate of that. Then your question will help guide readers to that answer.

Comment: @uhoh yes this does answer my question. Let me know if that is something that I need to do? Thank you